# How to assuredly suppress a DeprecationWarning in Python?

Tags: python, warnings

I believe this question was raised lots of times already but I have a specific use case where I can't solve the issue with many of the methods described on the web.

In one of my projects, I am using `joblib` library, and it shows `DeprecationWarning` because it uses `imp` library somewhere internally:

```
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed

def main():
    xs = Parallel()(delayed(lambda x: x**2)(i) for i in range(1, 6))
    print(sum(xs))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to filter out warning with interpreter option `-W` but it doesn't help:

```
$ python -W ignore example.py                                                                                                                   
[...]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py:47:
DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; 
see the module's documentation for alternative uses import imp
55
```

Also, I was trying an explicit filtering using `warnings` module but it is not helping also:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed

def main():
    xs = Parallel()(delayed(lambda x: x**2)(i) for i in range(1, 6))
    print(sum(xs))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I had similar issues with `matplotlib` module and some other third-party libraries.  Probably there are some other ways (i.e., env vars) but I don't understand why these solutions don't work.

Could anyone explain how the warnings system actually works in Python? It is possible that third-party libraries intentionally override client's warnings settings? I would say that this question is one of the most obscure topics for me.

Comment: Sklearn seems to enforce Warnings, see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2531) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612180/eliminating-warnings-from-scikit-learn). I have no solution.

Comment: Found it: the trick is to use "with" warnings while importing sklearn (or the depdendency that uses sklearn): `with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    import hdbscan` This will disable DeprecationWarning only for this module.

Comment: @Alex Would you mind extrapolating the useful trickery embedded in [your second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379418/how-to-assuredly-suppress-a-deprecationwarning-in-python#comment96120602_54379418) into a proper answer? We will all then upvote that into the stratosphere. (*Think of the karmic glory that could be yours.*)

Comment: See my answer below for a solution to this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting enough, that even following @Alex's advice, I still have warnings output, like this:

```py
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
    from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed

def main():
    xs = Parallel()(delayed(lambda x: x**2)(i) for i in range(1, 6))
    print(sum(xs))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# $ python -W ignore example.py
# [...]
# DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; 
# see the module's documentation for alternative uses
#  import imp
# 55
```

So eventually, I decided to do it in a very hacky way and disable all warnings because I am bit tired of looking for a proper way to deal with them. (Not only for this library, but for many others that seem to be very eager about bombarding you with non-suppressible warnings).

```
import warnings
def noop(*args, **kargs): pass
warnings.warn = noop
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed

def main():
    xs = Parallel()(delayed(lambda x: x**2)(i) for i in range(1, 6))
    print(sum(xs))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I use @Alex's advice wrongly or some of you have a better solution, I would be glad to accept it as an answer.

---

**Update 1**

Ok, it seems that it is pretty hard to influence the warnings, raised somewhere internally in the package. So probably the most simple thing would be to just replace `warnings.warn` with `noop`, or maybe somehow import the internal dependencies in advance and suppress them with a context manager.

---

**Update 2**

Some time ago I found one more possible way to deal with warnings. You can redirect them into logging. In case if no logger is explicitly configured, these warnings are essentially suppressed. It works for Jupyter and some libraries I've tested.

```
import logging
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

Comment: did you check that you're really using Parallel from sklearn? As far as I know, it was excluded from sklearn in newer versions and is maintained as a separate package now

Comment: @Alex hey, thank you for the response! The code I've shown above is an exact snippet I am using. If you would like, you can save it to `export.py` and see that it uses `Parallel` from sklearn but still shows the warning. By the way, when I am using your code, I still get the warning when trying to import `hdbscan` :) Not sure why it happens. Probably some versions of sklearn import the joblib internally somewhere and therefore my context managers have no effect.

Comment: Not sure, but a possible explanation could be [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9857) for sklearn, which seems to mess with the parent warnings.filterwarnings settings

Comment: Update 2 successfully suppressed deprecation warnings for older versions of [hvac](https://hvac.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 8):

As requested, here's the answer as a separate post:

The trick is to use "with" warnings while importing `sklearn` (or the dependency that uses sklearn, in my case it was the `hdbscan` package):

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    # filter sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py:268:
    # DeprecationWarning: check_pickle is deprecated
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
    import hdbscan
```

This will disable DeprecationWarning only for this module (because `warnings`-modification is attached to the with-block).

It is important to put this statement at the first position in your code where the module is imported, otherwise it won't work. E.g. if I was loading `hdbscan` in `__init__.py`, and the above code block appears in some sub-class that also loads `hdbscan`, I would still get the DeprecationWarning because Python ignores any subsequent `import` statement if the module/package is already loaded.

Therefore, it is important to check which modules/packages uses `joblib\parallel.py` and where those, from a linear code-perspective, are earliest loaded to the python object heap.

**[EDIT]**

As @devforfu points out in comments, the above solution does not work (anymore). I've looked again into this and since [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) `DeprecationWarning is once again shown by default when triggered directly by code in __main__.`. Furthermore, `ignore` warnings doesn't seem to work when a Dependency explicitly loads a depreciated module of some other package.

This is what appears to happen in my `hdbscan` example, which loads the depreciated modules `sklearn.external.six` and `sklearn.externals.joblib`.

**Here's how to finally solve this annoying issue:**

- make sure you've explicitly installed the standalone packages that are depreciated, e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge joblib six`
- create a fake import that will override the dependency import, e.g.:

```py
try:
    sys.modules['sklearn.externals.six'] = __import__('six')
    sys.modules['sklearn.externals.joblib'] = __import__('joblib')
    import hdbscan
except ImportError:
    import hdbscan
```

If there's no import error, standalone six and joblib will be used. Otherwise, e.g. if a user hasn't installed six or joblib, the program will still work (because it loads both modules from sklearn.externals), but it will show the depreciation warning.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense! So if I have some package that uses _another_ package, that gives warning, I cannot suppress it, right? Except if I import this _another_ package first.

Comment: In this case, you would add the _some package_ that loads _another package_ to the code block above. This is what I did: in my case, `hdbscan` was importing sklearn and I tried to get rid of the `check_pickle` warning. So I added hdbscan (not sklearn, which is not a direct dependency in my package)