# What is this warning: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1)

Tags: python, machine-learning

How can I handle this warning??

```
Warning (from warnings module):

  File "C:\Users\SAMSUNG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py", line 762
    extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
```

```
urls_data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
TEST_SIZE = 0.001
type(urls_data)
urls_data.head()

def makeTokens(f):
    tkns_BySlash = str(f.encode('utf-8')).split('/')
    total_Tokens = []
    for i in tkns_BySlash :
        tokens = str(i).split('-')
        tkns_ByDot = []
        for j in range(0, len(tokens)):
            temp_Tokens = str(tokens[j]).split('.')
            tkns_ByDot = tkns_ByDot + temp_Tokens
        total_Tokens = total_Tokens + tokens + tkns_ByDot
    total_Tokens = list(set(total_Tokens))
    if 'com' in total_Tokens:
        total_Tokens.remove('com')
    return total_Tokens

y = urls_data["label"]
url_list = urls_data["url"]
#Data Preprocessing
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=makeTokens)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(url_list)

#Split Train set and Test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = TEST_SIZE, random_state = 42)
###############################logit
logit = LogisticRegression()
logit.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and this is my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612180/eliminating-warnings-from-scikit-learn

Comment: What code originated this error? Please edit the post to include more context.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change

`logit = LogisticRegression()`

to

`logit = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000)`

and try again.

(Default parameter `max_iter` of `LogisticRegression()` equals 1000, so any number larger than 1000 is fine, not necessarily 10000)

You may also standardize your data as the warning said, with `sklearn.preprocessing.scale()`.

Comment: Just commenting that according to [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html?highlight=logisticregression#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression) default of max_iter equals 100, not 1000