# Python: how to ignore warnings when use PARALLEL techniques in code?

Tags: python, warnings

I know one common way to ignore warnings in Python is to use:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

And I do put these two lines up-above `import <package-to-ignore>` , it didn't work, warnings still poped up, and I also tried to add `warnings.filterwarnings`   multiple times, still not working.
The package I use is `sklearn` and some lines have **parallel processing**. I know this is the reason but I don't know how to fix it.
Appreciated if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612180/eliminating-warnings-from-scikit-learn)?

```
def warn(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
import warnings
warnings.warn = warn

#... import sklearn stuff...
```

Comment: Still not working(same problem 'What about when doing GridSearchCV in parallel' had been asked in comment under this answer), I tried to change some of the score functions to avoid this prob though.